# HighChart: Stacked Column Chart with dropdown

Tags: javascript, d3.js, highcharts, crossfilter, stacked-chart

I am trying to replicate [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked) using d3.js

So far I have managed to build a stacked bar chart that shows all data but my purpose is to filter the csv and bind the new data to my chart based on the user selection of country in a combo.

Here is my code:

```
  var outerWidth = 500;
  var outerHeight = 250;
  var margin = { left: 90, top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40 };
  var barPadding = 0.2;
  var xColumn = "City";
  var yColumn = "Population";
  var colorColumn = "Year";
  var layerColumn = colorColumn;
  var innerWidth  = outerWidth  - margin.left - margin.right;
  var innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top  - margin.bottom;
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  outerWidth)
    .attr("height", outerHeight);
  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  var xAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")");
  var yAxisG = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis");
  var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeBands([0, innerWidth], barPadding);
  var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([innerHeight, 0]);
  var colorScale = d3.scale.category10();
  // Use a modified SI formatter that uses "B" for Billion.
  var siFormat = d3.format("s");
  var customTickFormat = function (d){
    return siFormat(d).replace("G", "B");
  };
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom")
    .outerTickSize(0);
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left")
    .ticks(5)
    .tickFormat(customTickFormat)
    .outerTickSize(0);
  function render(data){
    var nested = d3.nest()
      .key(function (d){ return d[layerColumn]; })
      .entries(data)
    var stack = d3.layout.stack()
      .y(function (d){ return d[yColumn]; })
      .values(function (d){ return d.values; });
    var layers = stack(nested);
    xScale.domain(layers[0].values.map(function (d){
      return d[xColumn];
    }));
    yScale.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(layers, function (layer){
        return d3.max(layer.values, function (d){
          return d.y0 + d.y;
        });
      })
    ]);
    colorScale.domain(layers.map(function (layer){
      return layer.key;
    }));
    xAxisG.call(xAxis);
    yAxisG.call(yAxis);
    var layerGroups = g.selectAll(".layer").data(layers);
    layerGroups.enter().append("g").attr("class", "layer");
    layerGroups.exit().remove();
    layerGroups.style("fill", function (d){
      return colorScale(d.key);
    });
    var bars = layerGroups.selectAll("rect").data(function (d){
      return d.values;
    });
    bars.enter().append("rect")
    bars.exit().remove();
    bars
      .attr("x", function (d){ return xScale(d[xColumn]); })
      .attr("y", function (d){ return yScale(d.y0 + d.y); })
      .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
      .attr("height", function (d){ return innerHeight - yScale(d.y); })
  }
  function type(d){
    d.Population = +d.Population;
    return d;
  }
  d3.csv("data.csv", type, render);
</script>
```

Here is the sample data in data.csv

```
Country City Year Population

US     Dallas 2010 1000
US     Dallas 2011 1200
UK     London 2010 700
UK     London 2011  850
US     Chicago  2010 1250
US     Chicago  2011  1300
```

Comment: Why d3.js? Why not Highcharts? Highcharts are awesome :D

Comment: Can you show me an example with similar functionality using highcharts?

Comment: Yes, I could show you an example with exact functionality using Highcharts if you could explain a bit more how the selection is done, but it will be based on dynamic change of data in series. It can be done by series.update()/series.setData() - [example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/wxLw8g4y/) or if you are using data module and want to load different data (although first approach seems more optimal) - [example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/3wc9tyh7/2/).

Comment: I am looking for something very similar to example 1. If you saw the sample data I have shown, The data in the csv contains columns for country,city,year,population.what i would want is a dropdown with country name. City on x-axis, stacked column for each city split by year. For example if i select US then the chart should have 2 bars, dallas and chicago with stack of population by year. It would be great if you can show me how the data is read from csv rather than stroing values in a variable. Let me know if this makes sense or you need more info. many thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I got it.  More info you posted was very useful - thank you. It is a matter of data parsing. I posted my code as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to reload chart's data through reloading and reparsing `CSV`and using Highcharts official [data module](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/data-module), but it is more efficient to load and parse data once, next update/rebuild chart when needed.

`Example:` http://jsfiddle.net/1wgqyyg9/

```js
// Emulate get
$.get = function(id, fn) {
  fn(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
};

$(function() {
  var chartOptions = {
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: 'Total population over years'
        },
        stackLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
          }
        }
      },
      legend: {
        align: 'right',
        x: -30,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 25,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
        borderColor: '#CCC',
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
        pointFormat: '{point.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
            style: {
              textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      series: []
    };

  //load CSV - emulated infile to show in JSFiddle
  $.get('data.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n'),
       countries = {};

    // Iterate over the lines and create data sets - countries
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
      var items = line.split(','),
        yearFound = false,
        country, city, year, population;

      if (lineNo === 0) {  // header line containes info
      }          // rest of lines contain data
      else {
       country = items[0],
        city = items[1],
        year = items[2],
        population = items[3];
       // check if new country
        if(countries[country] === undefined) {
         countries[country] = [{
           name: year,
            data: [{name: city, y: parseInt(population)}]
          }];
        } else {
         $.each(countries[country], function(yearNo, countryYear){
           if(year === countryYear.name) {
             yearFound = true;
              countryYear.data.push({name: city, y: parseInt(population)});
             return false; //exit this each loop
            }
          });
          if(!yearFound) { // new year
           countries[country].push({
             name: year,
             data: [{name: city, y: parseInt(population)}]
            });
          }
        }
      }
    });
    // sort cities in year series
    $.each(countries, function(countryName,country){
     $('#selectCountry')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",countryName)
         .text(countryName)); 
         
     $.each(country, function(j,year){
       year.data.sort(function(a,b){
         a.name > b.name;
        });
      });
    });
    
    $("#selectCountry").change(function(){ 
        var selected = this.value;
        if(selected) {
          chartOptions.series = $.extend(true, [], countries[selected]); // do deep copy to keep original data
          Highcharts.chart('container',chartOptions);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<select id="selectCountry">
  <option>Select country</option>
</select>

<pre id="data.csv" style="display: none">Country,City,Year,Population
US,Dallas,2010,1000
US,Dallas,2011,1200
UK,London,2010,700
UK,London,2011,850
US,Chicago,2010,1250
US,Chicago,2011,1300</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kacper. Couple of more qus:
1. how can I show values/lable on the chart?
2. Consider I have one more dimension as gender whose filter is a radio button(either male or female). Will I need to create another filter function for this?

Once again. I am really thankful to you. I learnt a lot from this example

Comment: @Glenn 1. Right on chart there are [dataLabels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<column>.dataLabels) (in columns) and [stackLabels](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.stackLabels) (on top of stacks) - they can be customized via API, so they can show different or more data. It is also possible to add custom labels using [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.label). What kind of info would you like to show? and where?

Comment: @Glenn 2. There are many ways of solving this problem. One of them might be to create bigger data structure that will hold different data sets for different genders - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/3y8f3833/)

Comment: Kacper, It's working like a charm. Thanks for your help. 
One Question: What is the significance of <pre> tag. My dataset is pretty large. Cant we read the data from csv rather than <pre> ?

Comment: Kacper, the next thing I would like to do is create few more charts and display them on the same page. I tried adding a line chart on this page but it isnt appearing on the browser at all.

Comment: @Glenn I used HTML to store CSV data because JSFidddle doesn't allow mulitiple files - you could use CSV in your project instead. For the next thing - could you post a live example? Example with more charts: http://jsfiddle.net/3y8f3833/1/

Comment: When I tried running the code after removing <pre> tag, the chart did not appear. regarding the other charts, consider a dashboard with line, gauge, pie with the same data on the same page. For example if I click on Year in our example, it takes me to a pie with distribution of population by month for the city.

Comment: @Glenn If you want to remove <pre>, then also remove first few lines of the JS ($.get() override) - then first chart will be visible if CSV file is loaded successfully. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3y8f3833/2/

Comment: I am still unable to run :( Can I get your email id so that i can send you my code?

Comment: Can i change the colors or create my own theme? The next thing for me is to create a similar chart with different dimension on x-axis. I would like to display that chart adjacent to first chart. I tried following this example: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/4GaVj/  but I have been getting an error "function highcharts does not exit"

Comment: @Glenn You can contact me through Highcharts forum (topic/post or PM) or any other Highcharts Support comunication channel - http://www.highcharts.com/support The error might be coming from Highcahrs not being yet loaded on your site - in the fiddle you posted JavaScript load type is set to onDomready (setting for JS in JSFiddle shows when you click on JAVASCRIPT text in section with JS code)

Comment: Kacper, I want to add a static filter to the data. For example if we have continent column in the csv and i always want to show data for Europe only. I do not wish to display the filter on Front End for user selection, I just want to have this in my code so that the data which is displayed is for European countries.

Comment: If you do not want to display filter on front/client end, then you could consider creating filtered data source (like JSON or CSV) and send only the data that client needs. Another option might be to hard-code selection - http://jsfiddle.net/3y8f3833/3/ 
`/* create a chart */
    countries = allData.countriesM;
    chartOptions.series = $.extend(true, [], countries['US']); /* do deep copy to keep original data */
    Highcharts.chart('container',chartOptions);`

Comment: consider a different dimension(Continent) altogether. I still want to apply filter on country and gender and display only rows where continent is 'Europe'

Comment: @Glenn Each next dimension will just cause more nested data structure (similar as gender was added), so I see no problem here. It will be easier to establish data structure in the beginning and create a data parser later on instead of changing and adding new features. It doesn't matter how many dimensions data will have - parsed data structure will be just more or less nested. In case you will have too many dimensions and data structure will become too nested, then you will end up with huge data structure of which you are using only a small percentage, but user can swap data client side.

Comment: Ok make sense. Thanks. Can you tell me in where do I hardcode as Continent="Europe"?

Comment: @Glenn You mean when data has another column named "Continent"?

Comment: Yes. I have a different column as Continent which contains values like Europe,Asia, America etc

Comment: @Glenn Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/3y8f3833/4/ Added new column, nested all data, changed selection building. Please note some data requirements in jsfiddle JS comment.

Comment: Kacper, I am extremely thankful to you buddy :)
Can you create another example and hardcode America?

Comment: You are welcome. Like continent selection is hard-coded to America? Yes, just remove/comment out some code and hard-code 'America' as selected continent - http://jsfiddle.net/3y8f3833/5/

Comment: About the second question - you could set width to `50%` and `float: left;` in containers styles - example: http://jsfiddle.net/3y8f3833/6/

Comment: is there a way i can reduce the chart width? I want to minimize the width so that I can show another chart on the right side.
What I mean is i want to create some space on the right side to accomodate another chart.
I tried reducing the width in <div> but there is no impact on the chart width.

Comment: Thanks Kacper, I have container2 which is right now appearing under container1 on the screen. i want to place container2 towards the right of container.

Comment: Regarding the hard coded continent. Can we remove it from the display so it is not visible to the user

Comment: 2 charts - strange, I see them as one by one in a single row. What browser and OS are you using? Try this one - http://jsfiddle.net/3y8f3833/7/. About hard-coded: yes, just remove <span> in HTML - JS code is not using it.

Comment: Is there a way I can change the colors in RGB format?

Comment: @Glenn Chart's [colors](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors)? Yes. Series color? Yes - http://jsfiddle.net/brgpanco/

Comment: Chart colors, in the example it is only 1 color. How can I have  pass multiple rgb color codes. In the stacked column chart example, I wish to give different colors to years

Comment: @Glenn If you wish to have more colors for a single series, then you could define colors per data point or set [`colorByPoint`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<column>.colorByPoint) to true and then use an [array of colors from chart settings](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#colors) or from [series settings](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<column>.colors).